React hook form and date picker do not get changes
I have a date range input component that I need to integrate with react-hook-form and Input of NextUI but when I do not set the to value the validation not work.
const formSchema = z.object({
  duration: z.object({
        from: z.string().min(8, { message: "تاریخ شروع ضروری میباشد" }),
        to: z.string().min(8, { message: "تاریخ پایان ضروری میباشد" }),
    })
});

import { Input } from "@nextui-org/input";
import { DateObject } from "react-multi-date-picker";

const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof formSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
    mode: "onSubmit",
    defaultValues: {
       duration: {
          from: "",
          to: ""
       }
    },
  });
<DateInput
    range
    minDate={new DateObject().add(1, 'day')}
    placeholder="از تاریخ ~ تا تاریخ"
    onChange={(value: DateObject[]) => {
      if (value[0]) {
          form.setValue('duration.from', value[0].unix.toString())
      }
      if (value[1]) {
         form.setValue('duration.to', value[1].unix.toString())
      }
    }}
    render={(value, openCalendar) => {
       return (
           <Controller
              name="duration"
              control={control}
              render={({ field, formState: { errors: { duration } } }) => {
                   return (
                      <Input
                        onClick={openCalendar}
                        value={value}
                        errorMessage={duration?.from?.message || duration?.to?.message}
                        isInvalid={!!duration?.from || !!duration?.to}
                        variant="faded"
                        label="از تاریخ ~ تا تاریخ"
                      />
                    );
               }}
            />

          )
        }}
      />

